# Where are the QuickTime video recordings saved

Tags: quicktime

I recorded a video using QuickTime, but cannot find the file.

Where is the file saved and how do I find it?

Comment: The QuickTime movie recording isn't saved automatically, you'll be prompted to save it upon quitting the app. Or you'll need to save it manually. Check if QuickTime app is still open and the title bar says "Untitled".